# Reset a dataframe to best predict variable classes

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which is a mix of; strings, factors, and numerical class variables. I need all the strings to be congruent so I uppercase the dataframe.

```
# Create dataframe
df <- data.frame(String=c("string", "String", "STRING"), Numeric=c(2,3,5), Factor=c("A","B","C"))
df$String <- as.character(df$String)
df$Numeric <- as.numeric(df$Numeric)
df$Factor <- as.factor(df$Factor)


# Uppercase dataframe
df <- mutate_all(df, funs(toupper))
```

This has now made every column a character class. I can now do a write.csv then a read.csv to set all the numeric variables back into their correct class (then I manually assign which variables are factors and which are strings if an error was made). Is there a way to reset a dataframe to it's best guess for variable classes without doing a write.csv to read.csv

Comment: It might be better to only modify the character columns in the first place with `df %>% mutate_if(is.character, toupper)`